# There is a problem with the interpreter setup in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

There is a problem with the interpreter setup in `Pycharm`.

```
Error configuring SDK: Illegal char <:> at index 41: C:\Users\korea\anaconda3\envs\wonyong3\ D:\Developments\deeplab_test\research.
Please make sure that C:\Users\korea\anaconda3\envs\wonyong3\python.exe is a valid home path for this SDK type.
```

[image]

**how can I fix it?**